# HTML5 App - New Safari Session Starts from Home Screen

Tags: visualforce, html5

I have an HTML5 page setup.  When a user saves the page to their homescreen (i.e. to them, "install the app"), if they minimize (i.e. don't close) their browser then click the "app" again, it starts a new Salesforce session rather than retaining the one in the running browser.

Is there a way to keep the app from starting up a new session, or is this a limitation of Safari Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour for mobile safari - the only way for the app to retain any information is through local storage, although this isn't secure and I doubt you'd be able to retain your Salesforce session :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759372/prevent-web-app-restart-on-ipad-task-switch/7607917#7607917

I've switched most of our HTML5 applications over to Salesforce1 as this uses oauth to refresh the user session without requiring the user to enter their credentials again.

Comment: Thanks Bob;  this is what I suspected.

I was looking at moving over to Salesforce1 yesterday, looks like we'll move down this path.